# Why is client disconnecting and reconnecting after server receives emit?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, mongoose

In my `socket.io` application (version 1.0.6) I have many events that follow the same schema:

Client emits `'some client emit'` with data, Server receives `'some client emit'`, saves some object in `mongoose` and emits `'some server emit'` with parsed data to other Clients and a separate `'some server emit'` with specific data to the sending Client.

For example, if the client code includes:

```
...
console.log('emitting some client emit');
this.socket.emit('some client emit', {prop1: 'val1', prop2: 'val2'});
...
this.socket.on('some server emit', function(data){
   console.log('some server emit', data);
   if(data.doSomething){
      ...
   }
   ...
}

this.socket.on('error', function(err){
   console.log('error', err);
}
...
```

then the server code includes:

```
...
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log(socket.id, 'connected');
   ... deal with connect 

   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('socket', socket.id, 'disconnected');
      ... deal with disconnect
   }

   socket.on('some client emit', function(data){
      console.log('some client emit', data);
      var newThing = new Thing({
         prop1: data.prop1,
         prop2: data.prop2
      });

      newThing.save(function(err){ // a mongoose object
         if(err){
            console.log('error saving thing', err);
            socket.emit('error', err);
         } else {
            console.log('saving successful');
            socket.emit('some server emit', {thing: newThing, doSomething: true});
            for (var i = 0; i < someListOfSocketIds.length; i++)
                socket.broadcast.to(someListOfSocketIds[i]).emit('some server emit', {thing: newThing, doSomething: false});
         }
      }
      console.log('end of some client emit');
   }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the client emits `'some client emit'`, the server gets the event and sends `'some server emit'` to the list of socket ids and the sending client. All clients receive the emit BUT THEN **the original sending client gets the saving error and disconnects and reconnects.**

So the console of the sending client is as such:

```
 - emitting some client emit
 - some server emit {prop1: 'val1', prop2: 'val2', _id: <some guid>}
 - error {type: "TransportError", description: TypeError, stack: "Error: parser decode error
    at WS.Transport.onError (http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js:1:28005)
    at WS.Transport.onData (http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js:1:28768)",
    message: "parser decode error", ...}
```

And the console of the server is:

```
 - *client-socket-id* connected
 - some client emit  {prop1: 'val1', prop2: 'val2'}
 - saving successful
 - end of some client emit
 - socket *client-socket-id* disconnected
 - *client-socket-id* connected
```

It should be noted that **newThing** actually does make it into the DB, the other clients do get their emits, and at no point does the server code `"console.log('error saving thing', err);"` get run. This is really confusing to me.

Comment: To clarify and possibly help others that might be having this issue as I was: **A client's socket is automatically disconnected if there is a runtime error.** It was surprisingly hard to find anything documenting this.

Comment: I realize that was very vague but it I can't seem to narrow it down anymore than that. An example of the kind of errors that caused the disconnect/reconnect behaviour are simply attempting to access a null field or pretty much any basic runtime error that is only found using breakpoints on the client. I too searched for any kind of documentation but couldn't find anything. After I fixed my few bugs the code worked fine and every time I see the same functionality its because of a similar runtime error on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that if there is a runtime error, like comparing a variable to a list instead of the list's length eg,

```
for (var i = 0; i < list; i++){ ...
}
```

or accessing a property of a null variable:

```
var thing;
if (thing.someNullPropery == ''){ ...
}
```

,
in the client's receiving code:

```
 this.socket.on('some server emit', function(data){ ...
 }
```

then the socket immediately disconnects and since the client is still on the page it then connects resulting in a disconnect/reconnect behaviour. I fixed my problem but if anyone else has this issue, console.log everywhere!